# How do I add a right-click option to search the web using a selected file's name?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, registry, regedit

I'm looking to add an option to the right-click menu in Windows Explorer that will launch Chrome and search a specific site for that file's name.  To be a little more specific, I want to be able to do this on a video file and then look for available subtitles for it.  I'm aware that there are a number of programs that can do some variation of this, but after trying out a bunch of them, I haven't quite found what I want. Not only that, but I'd rather use some lightweight, native code than having to install another program.

The closest thing to a guide that I've found is [in this post](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r29686640-), but it doesn't quite work.  Of course, I've tried cleaning it up for my needs, but it still doesn't work, so I think there's a flaw in there.  Here's what I have so far...

Running Command Prompt as Administrator, I executed these two lines to add them to the Registry:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search" /d "Subtitle Search"
REG ADD "HKLM\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search\Command" /d "C:\My Projects\My Code\SubtitleSearch.bat ""%1"""
```

The, I create a batch file (SubtitleSearch.bat) with the following:

```
set xGOOGLESEARCH=%~nx1
cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://subscene.com/subtitles/title?q=%xGOOGLESEARCH%"
```

That seems pretty straightforward, but it doesn't work.  Instead, ***Windows thinks I'm trying to open the file*** and asks me what program to use.  If I choose Chrome, incidentally, it actually starts playing the video in a tab.

I'm convinced the problem is with the Registry code, but I can't figure out how to tell the system that I don't want to open the file I'm right-clicking on; I just want to use its filename.  I'm familiar with the Registry, but not skilled enough to see what the issue is.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you checked if the right value is in the registry (regarding the quotes and all). Also, why not just execute the url using `start http://subscene.com/subtitles/title?q=%xGOOGLESEARCH%`. It will start it in the default browser, regardless of which one it is or where it is installed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes - it's been added to the registry successfully.

Comment: With regards to the execution of the search, your method is probably just as good, but I can't get to that step in the process regardless. I did run that piece independently, BTW, and it executed just fine.

Comment: Have you tried to **directly make a .reg file**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Process 1st argument passed.
if "%~1" == "/?" goto :help
if "%~1" == "/query" goto :query
if "%~1" == "/register" goto :register
if "%~1" == "/unregister" goto :unregister
if "%~1" == "" exit /b 1
goto :search
exit /b 0


:help
echo Open chrome search page with filename as the item to search.
echo:
echo Syntax: "%~nx0" keyword
echo:
echo Arguments:
echo   /?
echo       This help message.
echo   /query
echo       View a query of registered entries.
echo   /register
echo       Register context menu entries.
echo   /unregister
echo       Unregister context menu entries.
exit /b 0


:query
reg query "HKLM\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search" /s
exit /b 0


:register
echo Register subtitle search
reg add "HKLM\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search" /d "Subtitle Search" /f
reg add "HKLM\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search\Command" /d "\"%~f0\" \"%%1\"" /f
if errorlevel 1 net session >nul 2>&1 || echo Require admin to register.
exit /b 0


:search
rem Filename as item to search. If want extension also, use nx modifiers instead of just n.
set "search=%~n1"

rem URL used as the search engine.
:: set "url=https://www.google.com/search?q="
set "url=https://www.startpage.com/do/search/?q="
:: set "url=http://subscene.com/subtitles/title?q="

rem Use start so that the window does not remain open. CMD not being called so surrounding double quotes not stripped.
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%url%%search%"

rem View CMD /?. Surrounding double quotes and more than 1 pair may have the outer pair stripped. Add another escaped pair to be stripped.
:: cmd /s /c ^""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%url%%search%"^"

rem Uncomment command to check commandline of cmd.exe.
:: wmic process where caption="cmd.exe" get commandline & pause
exit /b 0


:unregister
echo Unregister subtitle search
reg delete "HKLM\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search" /f
if errorlevel 1 net session >nul 2>&1 || echo Require admin to unregister.
exit /b 0
```

Problems in your code:

- Escape inner double quotes with backslashes when using `reg` command i.e. `""""` to `"\"\""`.
- Escape `%` sign with another `%` so that `reg` can add literal `%1` i.e. `%1` to `%%1`.
- The "*Windows thinks I'm trying to open the file*" is probably caused by the double quoting issue as I have not yet reproduced.
- CMD may strip double quotes if the command has surrounding double quotes and has more then 2 double quotes.
  View `cmd /?` for parsing rules:

  > If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
  >      the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
  >      used to process quote (") characters:
  >
  > 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
  >         on the command line are preserved:
  >
  >    - no /S switch
  >    - exactly two quote characters
  >    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
  >         where special is one of: &<>()@^|
  >    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
  >         two quote characters
  >    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
  >         of an executable file.
  > 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
  >         a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
  >         remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
  >         any text after the last quote character.

I have made the script all in one so you can register by:

```
search /register
```

Output expected:

> ```
> Register subtitle search
> The operation completed successfully.
> The operation completed successfully.
> ```

Ensure a Command Prompt is used as Administrator as registering to `HKLM` branch may require it. Where the script is located is the path added to registry. So do not register just anywhere and move it later to its correct path.

Query the registry entries by:

```
search /query
```

Output expected:

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search
>     (Default)    REG_SZ    Subtitle Search
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search\Command
>     (Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\My Projects\My Code\search.cmd" "%1"
> ```

View help message by:

```
search /?
```

If uncomment `wmic` command in the `:search` label, Output in open console from doing a search is:

> ```
> CommandLine
> cmd /c ""C:\My Projects\My Code\search.cmd" "C:\My Projects\My Code\Alice In Wonderland.mp4""
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

This command by default should be disabled as a comment or removed as only added for checking the command line.

Chrome opens at this URL if *startpage.com* is used for search engine:

> ```
> https://www.startpage.com/do/search/?q=Alice%20In%20Wonderland
> ```

If neither of those 2 arguments mentioned are not passed, and the 1st argument is something, then a search is done with Chrome. No arguments will just end the script as is useless to process nothing.

I cannot access the `subscene.com` site so I have added some other URLs for testing with.

The `cmd` command is disabled and use of `start` has been added so the console window closes and Chrome opens. I left `cmd` in the script so you can see that it can work.

To unregister:

```
search /unregister
```

Output expected:

> ```
> Unregister subtitle search
> The operation completed successfully.
> ```

Ensure a Command Prompt is used as Administrator as unregistering from `HKLM` branch may require it. Location of the script does not matter as it deletes the whole registry key.

Comment: Wow, this is such a thorough answer! **Thank you!** (_I had to read it quite a few times, but I think I finally understand._) I'm no Registry expert, so thank you for explaining my mistakes. More importantly, thank you for creating a comprehensive, all-in-one script!  I'm gonna try this out now, but I'm confused what you mean by _"No arguments will just end the script as is useless to process nothing."_ I understand the _register_ and _view help_ arguments... and I understand that using no argument would run the search, but then I'm lost. What other missing arguments would end the script?

Comment: I may not be following as well as I thought. I created the bat file, but registering it has unexpected results. If I simply copy the registry lines and run them in cmd (Admin) from the script location, I can see the registry item I originally created is updated with your code. **Perfect.** But then I wanted to see what would happen by running _/register_ from the bat file and... for some reason it changes back to my old value! How? Where is it even pulling that old value from? Running the lines in cmd fixes it and running from the script breaks it again.

Comment: No arguments means don't search or anything. Imagine if you double click on the file which passes no arguments. The script will just `exit` rather then try to process `""`. If you use context menu, very much doubt `""` will be passed as 1st argument, so it should be of no concern to normal operation. As for changing back to old value on register, I do not understand this as nothing in the code changes anything back. Depends where read from i.e. if read from entries from *HKCR* and if you registered in *HKCU* previously, then that will overrule *HKLM* that this script uses. The later is a guess

Answer (score 1):

The batch-file path contains spaces, so you have to surround it with quotes:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\software\Classes\*\shell\Subtitle Search\Command" /d "\"C:\My Projects\My Code\SubtitleSearch.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Thank you, but that gives me an <b>Invalid syntax</b> error when I try to add it.  While I typically understand the multiple quotation marks, I have to admit I'm confused here.  Shouldn't the first piece in quotes (HKLM\...) also have multiple quotation marks?

Comment: My bad, sorry, just tested it and updated the answer.

Comment: OK, that one adds to the Registry properly now.  Thank you.  Unfortunately, it only gets me back to square one.  Windows still thinks I'm trying to open the file with a different program when I try to run it from the right-click menu.

Comment: I'm on Win8, but I don't see how that could be a problem.  Unfortunately, I don't have a system with an earlier OS to test it myself.  On the right-click menu, it's sandwiched between <b>Open</b> and <b>Open as</b>, so that leads me to believe it's being inserted into the wrong section.  The placement doesn't bother me, I just wonder if it has something to do with what makes Windows think it should open the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need the ""%1"" stuff at the end of your commandline put in the Registry. The executable selected to open the file gets the target file implicitly as %1. No need to explicitly state that in your commandline. In fact, I think %1 is not even defined in that context, only inside of your batch file. The last part is probably interpreted as a literal parameter String, which does not make sense for the batch interpreter. Did you try a `echo %1` somewhere at the top of your batch file to check its value?

Edit: Dang! 4 years, 9 months to wait on further answers... I feel sorry for you :(

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Haha, it's been a while, but I kinda gave up and moved on. But now with all the extra time, I really want to get this working. (I should warn you I'm a little rusty, so please bear with me.) I can't tell you why the "%1" is there, other than it being in the code I originally started from, but I assumed that was the part that was getting the file name. Sadly, I just tried removing it and it didn't change anything. Also, I can't really try the "echo %1" idea because I can't get it to launch properly when I right-click, so I can't even get that far.

Comment: Well, since WindowsXP(?) 5 years ago there were a lot of changes in the Registry for Windows10 (64 Bit). Maybe you need to try to setup the command menu entries manually first to get this to work. Or you replace the "real" batch file with one that only does the echo + pause maybe. Also, you could add a `set /p filename=Movie filename: ` into your script somewhere at the start. And then try to drag&drop a file on the console window. The path should be inserted into the command prompt. Internally you need to wire the `%filename%` properly of course.

Comment: And there is the sendto folder you could try as well. Enter `shell:sendto` as address inside the file explorer to get there. If you add a shortcut to your script there, you can at least do a right click on any file, then select "send to" and then your script.

Comment: To be honest, I never thought of trying to add to the sendto folder and I didn't even realize it could be done so easily. It's definitely a possibility if this can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make a .reg file that creates a right click menu that does what you are trying to do? I am unclear of your objective so this is all I can do.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\StartChrome]
@="Start google chrome and search for ____ website"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\StartChrome\command]
@="cmd /min /c \"start chrome.exe google.com"
```

This is a .reg file that creates a right-click menu prompt that says "`Start google chrome and search for ____ website`" and then starts chrome and goes to Google.com. In the last `@=""` part, in the quotations, put what you want the right click to do when you activate it. In the first `@=""` part, you choose what the thing shouled say in the right click menu. If you want to get rid of the right-click menu option, go to the registry and go to the part of the registry you specified in the second and fourth lines and delete them. Then you can restart explorer and the options will be gone.

I tested this with brave instead of chrome replacing chrome.exe with brave.exe and it works as intended by opening google.com. In your command part of the reg file, %1 is the thing you right-click to bring up the prompt.
Here is my best attempt at trying to do what you may want:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\StartChrome]
@="Start google chrome and search for ____ website"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\StartChrome\command]
@="cmd /min /c \"start chrome.exe 'http://subscene.com/subtitles/title?q=%~nx1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda find another way for it,
first install Violentmonkey extension from Chrome store, then install this script [SubScene Searcher](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/388069-subscene-searcher)
Then create a bat file on sendto folder with the following:

```
set Subscene=%~nx1
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://subscene.com/subtitles/title?q=%Subscene%"
```

now you can search from Send to menu